# Using map python with key argument

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def myFunct(arg1=None,arg2=None,arg3=None):
    pass
```

I would like to use that function with a map function but with argument 1 and 3 only.
idea would be:

```
map(myFunct,list_arg1,list_arg3)
```

so each of the call would be `myFunct(value1,arg3=value3)`

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: Isn't it map possible to use with any function with iterable ? 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `lambda` to map the arguments to your keyword arguments.

```
def foo(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    return arg1 + arg3

list1 = [3, 4, 5]
list2 = [5, 6, 7]

print(list(map(lambda x, y: foo(arg1=x, arg3=y), list1, list2)))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. possible edit : test1 and test2 on the last line are iterables. So maybe name them list1, list2.

Comment: No problem. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to keep your function as is and modify what you are mapping over:

```
from itertools import repeat
def f(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):
    return sum((x,y,z))

map(f,range(1,10),repeat(0),range(21,30))
```

Although from a readability point of view, a simple generator expression might be preferable to any solution based on `map`, something along the lines of:

```
f(x = i,z = j) for i,j in zip(range(1,10),range(21,30)))
```